# Possible to use jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut and leave a child element visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My strong guess is that the answer to this question is no.

I have an element with a background image and I am trying to switch between several different background images with fadeIn and fadeOut - the only problem is that I want one of my child elements to stay visible.

Here's the snippet :

```js
$(function(){  
    var i =0;
    var images = ["http://example.com/images/image2.jpg","http://example.com/images/image3.jpg"];
    var image = $('header');
    image.css('background-image', 'url(http://example.com/images/image1.jpg)');
    setInterval(function(){  
        image.fadeOut(1000, function () {
            image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i] +')');
            image.fadeIn(1000);
        });
        if(i == (images.length - 1)){
            i = 0; 
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }, 5000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="header-content-inner">
            <h1>Text I Want To Keep</h1>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn How</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Nothing too crazy. My only problem is that on fadeIn and fadeOut, everything goes completely to white, whereas I would like to retain my h1 element above. The structure of the site works a lot better without moving that element out of the header, so if it's possible that would be much easier for me.

Comment: Add your 'image' as a div with `position:absolute` inside the header-content

Comment: If you were just changing the `background-image`, it wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I'm open to just changing it, but I'm worried that that might look jarring to the user

Comment: This might point you to a possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/hzSG8/2064/

Answer (score 1):

This won't work. fadeIn and fadeOut are using the opacity-property in css, which is changing the opacity for elements and all of their children.
As said before, `position:absolute` may be the right solution for you